# Right shift inconsistent behavior when shifting for type width (related to K&R Exercise 2-06)

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

While attempting to solve K&R Exercise 2-06, which goes:

> Write a function `setbits(x,p,n,y)` that returns `x` with the `n` bits that begin at position `p` set to the rightmost `n` bits of `y`, leaving the other bits unchanged.

I want to set `n` bits starting at position `p` (1st bit is `0`) to `1` but I'm running into some unexpected behavior.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned p = 24u, n = 8u;
    printf("(p + n) == %u\n", (p + n));
    unsigned m = (~0u >> (p + n));
    printf("m == %08x\n", m);
    m = (~0u >> (32u));
    printf("m == %08x\n", m);
    m = (~0u >> (p + n - 1)) >> 1;
    printf("m == %08x\n", m);
}
```

which prints:

```
(p + n) == 32
m == ffffffff
m == 00000000
m == 00000000
```

I would expect that in all 3 variants I'd get 0x0, but that's not the case (see below output). What am I missing here? It works as expected for `p = 23u`.

Here's the whole program for those interested:

```
/* **Exercise 2-6.** Write a function `setbits(x,p,n,y)` that returns `x` with
 * the `n` bits that begin at position `p` set to the rightmost `n` bits of `y`,
 * leaving the other bits unchanged.
 */

#include <stdio.h>

unsigned setbits(unsigned x, unsigned p, unsigned n, unsigned y)
{
    /* set target bits in x to 0 */
    x &= ~(~0u >> p & ~(~0u >> (p + n - 1) >> 1));
    /* get the rightmost `n` bits of `y` and put them at the correct position */
    unsigned ya = 0u;
    for (unsigned i = 0u; i < n; ++i) {
        ya >>= 1u;
        if (y & 1u)
            ya |= ~(~0u >> 1u);
        y >>= 1u;
    }
    ya >>= p;
    /* write the bits into x */
    x |= ya;
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned x = 0x12345678;
    unsigned y = 0xFFFFFF11;
    printf("0x%08X", setbits(x, 24, 8, y));
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: Shifting type width or more is undefined behvior. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3